# how to change the background color of flyout in uwp?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, flyout

I want to set menu flyout background either in c# or xaml.

[I want like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZeie.png)

```
<FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>             
     <MenuFlyout x:Name="Flyout">
        <MenuFlyout.Items >
           <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Add Expense" Click="AddExpense_Click"/>
           <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Add Friends" Click="AddFriends_Click"/>
        </MenuFlyout.Items>
     </MenuFlyout>
</FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
```

... And this is my xaml code for menu fly-out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your requirement, you could custom `MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle` like the following

```
<MenuFlyout x:Name="Flyout">
        <MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle>
            <Style TargetType="MenuFlyoutPresenter">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            </Style>
        </MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle>
        <MenuFlyout.Items >
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Add Expense" />
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Add Friends" />
        </MenuFlyout.Items>
</MenuFlyout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the FlyoutPresenterStyle, I think.